# Self-Compiled OpenSSL package gives certificate error on CentOS 7

Tags: c++, ssl, https, openssl, client

I am developing a C++ HTTP/HTTPS client application inside environment of CentOS/Redhat 7.7, which the OS comes with `OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips`. But I need at least `OpenSSL 1.1.1` for my application. So I compiled `OpenSSL 1.1.1f` from source.

My compilation configuration.

```
./Configure linux-x86_64 enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib64 --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local
```

The problem starts here.

Any requests I make with the new OpenSSL results with `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`. I spent some time switching HTTP clients for C++, which was a very tiring process, only to find out that the issue is with OpenSSL itself.

After a long research, the HTTP client I currently use, shared a ca-bundle inside it's repo. Including it into my project resolved the issue.

https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/blob/master/example/ca-bundle.crt

```
cli.set_ca_cert_path(./ca-bundle.crt);
```

Or with command line,

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -CAfile ./ca-bundle.crt
```

This all seems absurd, I never had to do anything like this before in my experience with developing HTTP clients. Therefore my questions:

- Is this a problem with CentOS 7 ?
- Did I make a mistake while compiling OpenSSL ? (Followed)

**Note:** Using `cli.set_ca_cert_path("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt");` also works (took me a long time to realize), but I never had to do this manually before, hence forgive my ignorance.

Thanks for your time.

**Edit:** With the help of some code,

```
const char* dir = getenv(X509_get_default_cert_dir_env());

if (!dir)
    dir = X509_get_default_cert_dir();

cout << dir << endl;
```

It would seem `dir` is `/usr/local/certs` which does not exist. But I also tried this with the default installed OpenSSL inside the OS. Which I would guess should point to the real certificates ?

**Edit2:** Using `/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem` also works.

Comment: 1. No 2. Likely.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I shared my compilation script, which is a short one. Can you point me in the right direction where I went wrong ?

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow must include all relevant information in the question itself. External links can stop working at any time, making the question meaningless. I'm certain that openssl's configuration script must have means to specify the path to the cert bundle. I'd have to look it up, but it should be just the matter of setting it up correctly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your input, the link I shared is not exactly relevant with the statement of the question. It just signifies I used an external ca-bundle file. For the matter of compilation, I went through https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation but it does not mention this. Took me a really long time to figure out the issue. Now I just want to find a universal way to prevent this issue, which it would seem about adding relevant code to my application, rather that tampering with OpenSSL.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html) help?

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, but the problem is there are different locations for this. Like `/etc/pki/tls`, `/etc/ssl/certs/`, `/etc/pki/tls/certs/`. I don't know about hard coding one of these into my application, hoping to find the right one. Isn't this a bad practise ? I feel like I am missing something obvious. Like, the openssl-devel installed with the system does not require this. Are these hard coded into `libssl.so` or `libssl.a` ?

Comment: Are these different locations on different systems?  Are you trying to make your code portable?  Presumably openssl-devel is compiled for the system it is targeted for, which means that the certificates folder can (somehow) be baked into the binary.  That's about all I know, sorry.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks for your comments, all these folders exists in my system. The cert files inside however, seem to link to a same file inside a more complicated folder (`/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem`).

Comment: So are some of these links, rather than actual folders?  Looks like the preferred location might have changed over time.  See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/62496/ssl-certificate-location-on-unix-linux